# Change <td> background color based on value

Tags: php, html, css

I was trying this one but doesn't seem to work for me. I took reference from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211245/change-colour-of-table-td-based-on-value). And below is my code:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$date = new DateTime();

$R1D2 = $date->setISODate($year,$week,1)->format('Y-m-d');

<td width="14.285%" <?php if ($R1D2 = $today): ?> style="background:#EEEEEE" <?php endif ?>>some content here </td>
```

The result is, all the cells changes its background even if it's not equal with `$today`

Comment: You need to use `if ($R1D2 == $today)`... a single `=` assigns a value, `==` does a comparison.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if ($R1D2 = $today):`

You are actually setting `$R1D2` as `$today`. Please change that line to:

`if ($R1D2 == $today):`

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize that `=` and `==` have different functions.

Comment: It's a useful mechanic that you may take advantage of in the future

Comment: @Richelle You even got a third, `===` which has yet another meaning. Read the post this was marked as a duplicate of. These are quite important to know...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'll take note of this. Many thanks.

Comment: If you are a person, which probably often does this type of mistake, you can use "yode-speaking"-style. Like (`true == $var`), since if you miss a equal sign there, you get a syntax error. In your case tho, this would not have made a difference. I made myself always use yoda-talk and I never made this error again (in over 8 years :P)